# Javascript onkeypress to restrict input between 1.00 to 0.00

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript function that will restrict a textbox to input values between 1.00 and 0.00 and also limits the user to input only numbers, single decimal point, single digit whole number and 2 decimal places. Thank you!

Comment: [`<input type="number" value="0.5" min="0" max="1" step="0.01"/>`](https://jsfiddle.net/patrob10114/jat1y93q/) Look ma, no JavaScript!

Comment: I need a restriction sir.